# Datatables load rows when scrolling to bottom

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using a dataTable in a scroll mode. I am getting the data through an ajax call in php. What I need to do is to initialize the table with 20 rows to start and then to load more rows when you scroll to the bottom of the table.

Here is my initial dataTable setup:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        scrollY: 200,
        paging: false,
        searching: false,
        info: false,
        stateSave: true
        ajax: {
            url: "scripts/some-php-file.php",
            type: "POST"
    });
});
```

Here is what I found for seeing if the dataTable scroll has hit the bottom:

```
$('.dataTables_scrollBody').scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
        // load more rows if they exist
});
```

I also need to be able to refresh the data every 10 seconds. When I do this I need to be able to remember the scroll position so that it won't go to the top of the page.

Here is what I found for that:

```
setInterval( function () {
    table.ajax.reload( null, false );
}, 30000 );
```

I am having trouble putting all of the pieces together.

The full functionality of this would be that when the page loads it only loads the first 20 rows into the dataTable. When the user scrolls to the bottom of the dataTable it will load up to 20 more rows if they exist. This will keep repeating until the end of the data set. Additionally the dataTable needs to refresh every 10 seconds and keep the scrolled position.